# Pandas: Need to find the Highest Salary by each team each year

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am trying to work on a simple data set of basketball players
which contains some essential columns given below:

```
year | teamID | playerID | salary
```

The data is given from year 1985-2016. I'm trying to find the **max mean salary provided by each team each year**.

I used `groupby` as below, at first:

```
mean_salary_by_year_team = \
salaries.groupby(['yearID', 'teamID'])[['salary']].agg(np.mean)
```

Now this gives me mean salary of each team and each year. But, how can I extract the maximum from 'salary' and corresponding 'teamID' for every year.

Please, do not give me exact code but an idea or functions I could refer to. I'll try and get back, if I still don't get the answer :)

Comment: The structure of Stack Overflow is such that your question would be better if you provided sample data, and expected an actual answer as opposed to an "idea". Hints aren't really encouraged here.

Comment: Maybe instead of `np.mean`, you could use a different aggregating function?

Comment: Can someone explain me why I have got 4 downvotes for the question? I don't mind downvotes, it'll just help me from next time :)

Answer (score 2):

I can only assume you are looking for something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'TeamID':[1,2,3,1,2,3], 'Salary':[100,200,300,150,350,250]})
df = df[['Year','TeamID','Salary']]
print('DATAFRAME:')
print(df)

print('MEAN SALARY:')
print(df.groupby('Year').agg({'Salary':'mean'}))

print('MAX SALARY:')
print(df.groupby('Year').apply(lambda x: x[x['Salary'] == x['Salary'].max()]))

print('MIN SALARY:')
print(df.groupby('Year').apply(lambda x: x[x['Salary'] == x['Salary'].min()]))
```

OUT:

```
DATAFRAME:
    Year  TeamID  Salary
0     1       1     100
1     1       2     200
2     1       3     300
3     2       1     150
4     2       2     350
5     2       3     250

MEAN SALARY:
      Salary
Year        
1        200
2        250

MAX SALARY:
        Year  TeamID  Salary
Year                        
1    2     1       3     300
2    4     2       2     350

MIN SALARY:
        Year  TeamID  Salary
Year                        
1    0     1       1     100
2    3     2       1     150
```

Comment: Thanks Chris :) I got what I was looking for. I was looking for the max salary function applied to salary column retaining other columns as well. In my case, this is second groupby() to be applied on top of the one I have already mentioned in question :) somehow I wasn't able to retain the 'teamID' column. Thanks for it